# Firing a Record triggered flow on the Service Appointment object on latest work order status change

Tags: trigger, fsl

I have a record triggered flow on the Service Appointment object and runs when a Service Appointment is created or modified on some fields like status, AppointmentType, ParentRecordType, Subject. The flow works well but I would also like this record trigger flow to execute when the work order status changes.

basically:

```
ID ParentrecordId = ServiceAppointment.ParentrecordId;
lineitem = [select workorder.status from workorderlineitem where id =:ParentrecordId]
```

Can this be done on the Service Appointment record triggered flow somehow or will I I need to set up a record trigger on the workorderlineitem object.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the record being updated would be the Work Order, you'll need a new triggered flow on that object.

If you're wanting to re-use the exact same logic, I'd recommend moving that into a new auto-launched flow which you could then call from both the Service Appointment and Work Order record triggered flows. This lets you maintain it all in one place while still being able to launch it from both objects.